# Room Database Migration Failed: ALTER TABLE to add multiple columns

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm upgrading my Database from version 3 to version 4 by providing migration from 3 to 4.

Here's my code for migration:

```java
private static Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE caption_table ADD COLUMN localVideoUrl TEXT;");
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE caption_table ADD COLUMN postType TEXT");
      database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE caption_table ADD COLUMN videoUrl TEXT");
    }
};
```

Here's the code which create room database

```java
this.mAppDataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDataBase.class, "my_db")
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3, MIGRATION_3_4)
                        .build();
```

Here's the piece of code that I have added on my PostModel

```java
@Expose
private String postType;

@Expose
private String videoUrl;

@Expose
private String localVideoUrl;

public String getPostType() {
    return postType;
}

public void setPostType(String postType) {
    this.postType = postType;
}

public String getVideoUrl() {
    return videoUrl;
}

public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
    this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
}

public String getLocalVideoUrl() {
    return localVideoUrl;
}

public void setLocalVideoUrl(String localVideoUrl) {
    this.localVideoUrl = localVideoUrl;
}
```

And below is the error I'm getting. The error is not related to the notNull property of room entity.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle
>   posts(com.myapp.Database.PostModel).
>
> Expected:
>       TableInfo{name='posts', columns={imageWidth=Column{name='imageWidth', type='INTEGER',
>   affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   localVideoUrl=Column{name='localVideoUrl', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   authorImageLocalUrl=Column{name='authorImageLocalUrl', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   videoUrl=Column{name='videoUrl', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   imageLocalUrl=Column{name='imageLocalUrl', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, postType=Column{name='postType',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   authorName=Column{name='authorName', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, imageUrl=Column{name='imageUrl',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true,
>   primaryKeyPosition=1}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   authorImageUrl=Column{name='authorImageUrl', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   imageHeight=Column{name='imageHeight', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
>   notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
>
> Found:
>       TableInfo{name='posts', columns={imageWidth=Column{name='imageWidth', type='INTEGER',
>   affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   authorImageLocalUrl=Column{name='authorImageLocalUrl', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   imageLocalUrl=Column{name='imageLocalUrl', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   authorName=Column{name='authorName', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
>   notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0}, imageUrl=Column{name='imageUrl',
>   type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true,
>   primaryKeyPosition=1}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   authorImageUrl=Column{name='authorImageUrl', type='TEXT',
>   affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0},
>   imageHeight=Column{name='imageHeight', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
>   notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: Yeah! I updated the room version and apparently it worked.

Comment: @RavindraBarthwal did you check my answer? It's weird that it's related to room's version and not the actual migration code

Answer (score 5):

Comparing the Expected vs. Found JSON that it's in your log, clearly, the error happens because the Table that was found doesn't have the 3 new columns you intended to add: `postType`, `videoUrl` and `localVideoUrl`. [(You can use this script to compare both JSON objects from the log)](https://hrankit.github.io/RoomSQLiteDifferenceFinder/)

The problem might be that in your migration code you are adding the new columns to a table named `caption_table`, whereas according to the log the table that fails is called `posts`. Try adjusting your migration code to add the new columns to the proper table.